# creating ipad app as non programmer

Tags: ipad

Does anyone have any links to software or sites for creating iPad apps for non programmers?  I'm looking for a WYSIWYG approach where I can link various pages together for a science education app.

Thanks.

Comment: My $0.02: If you can create an application with any toolset, you're (fit to be) a programmer. Conversely, if you're not (fit to be) a programmer, you will fail regardless of tools. There have been attempts to "bring programming to everyone" again and again, but the profession is still around. Well, there are some projects aimed at *introducing* children and teenagers to programming with a few users, but I don't know if it actually does good.

Comment: @delnan Agreed (not with the teenagers' part, but the others).